# Can some one operate 15 points lower during some part of the day and then return to normal?

Tags: measurement, methodology, iq

Few days back I took an IQ test ([online mensa norway](http://test.mensa.no/)) and found my IQ score to be 85. I actually had my IQ professionally tested 16 months ago by a psychologist when I was 18, and found out that I am pretty average (I got a score of 101).

I know that online tests are not valid, possibly explaining the lower score of 85. Nonetheless, [mensa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mensa_International) seems OK,as they claim that their test was correlated with other standardized tests.

So my question is: can IQ within- test (*i.e.*., test / re-test scores) vary over periods of time (say months to a few years, or even from a day to day basis?), or are the differences observed here better explained by between-test variability?

Comment: Your question is different from the anecdote you provide. The title talks about differences within a day, whereas the anecdote describes a seemingly much longer time frame.

Comment: I have attempted to frame the question better. Is the post reflecting your question, Sussan? Feel free to revert the changes or improve the post yourself to your liking.